# Different formulas for calculating power

Tags: energy, electricity, power

$P=IV$, $P=I^2R$, $P=\frac{V^2}{R}$, what are the distinctions between these equations? How do you know which equation to use when?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the power consumed by a lightbulb?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11732/)

Answer (score 1):

All are correct.

Note that that $I$ is current passing through the resistor and $V$ is potential difference across resistor. 
Use those equations in which you know the values of variables and not have to calculate them.

Why not use all equations in a question and satisfy yourself that all are correct?

These are just using ohm's law in $P=VI$. You must not use others if ohm's law does not apply.

Comment: What do you mean "you *may* not want to use others if ohm's law does not apply"? If Ohm's law does not apply, then the other equations are not generally valid. You *never* should use invalid equations! =p

Answer (score 0):

All the equations are really the same thing. Which one you use is dependent on the question given.

Power is the rate at which electrical energy is supplied to a circuit or consumed by a load.

$$Power=\frac{energy}{time}$$
$$P=\frac{QV}{t}$$

where $QV$ is the electrical energy consumed by the load with potential difference $V$ when $Q$ charge passes through
$$P=IV$$
Also,

$V=IR$

$$P=I^2R$$

$$P=\frac{V^2}{R}$$

so. two equations can be formed.

Example:

The voltage of a light bulb is 5V. Resitance is 0.5 ohms. Calculate the power rating.

In this case, the volatge and resistance is given. So, you can just use $P=\frac{V^2}{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Power is usually just quoted as energy/time, but this is actually a bit vague: Which energy, and which time?

When talking about energy, we either reference a system/physical object which the energy is a property of, or we are talking about the energy exchanged between two systems.

The time when used to talk about power implies a process occurring over some time interval; e.g. the energy of a system is changing for some amount of time or when taken to the instantaneous limit the power approaches some value.

The equation

$P = VI$

assumes there is some path which current is passing through; the current through the path is $I$ and the voltage difference across the path is $V$.  Current flows from high to low voltage, so the power $P$ is the potential energy the moving charges (i.e. the current) lose by traversing the path.

In the absence of friction/heat/other forces, this would result in kinetic energy being added to the moving charges at a rate of $-P$.  However: Whenever we do something interesting with electricity (e.g. lightbulbs, computers, starting a car) this energy added to the charges is taken away by whatever we use it for.

This brings us to your other equations.

If we have a resistor element that obeys Ohm's law**, then

$V = I R$.

Plugging this into our definition of power:

$P = I V = I (I R) = I^2 R$.

Or we could solve for $I$ instead:

$V = I R \implies I = V/R$

so

$P = I V = (V / R) V = V^2 / R$.

Now: to get from here to other useful questions such as how much power a lightbulb uses, we have to make some assumptions about how the device works.  Usually we assume *steady state*, i.e. the current/voltage don't change over time, which means that all of the energy the charges acquire is used up by whatever device we're running the current through.

In other words, assuming that the power from these formulas is the power used by a device is usually safe, but only when talking about steady state systems.  The exception to this is when we're talking about the power source; in this case conservation of energy tells us that the power the charges acquire must come from the power source.

So in short: $P = V I$ is always valid provided you're talking about the power given to the charges/taken from the power source, and the other two equations only hold for resistor elements which obey Ohm's law (with the same definition for power).  You can use these for other quantities however, as long as you're granted the right assumptions such as steady state systems.

** Note that you don't necessarily need Ohm's law to be true; resistance can be considered a function and not just a constant value and as long as you know this function you can safely use the formulas anytime.