# When do I use the various power-related equations?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Can someone please tell me when it is appropriate to use the equations $P=IV$, $P=I^2R$ and $P=V^2/R$?

Comment: Aside from the "I know two of these values and not the third" (e.g., I know I and V, but not R) type of scenario?

Comment: Yes, when should these be used- working out kWh in domestic usage and cost to householder things like that. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the power consumed by a lightbulb?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11732/)

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is when you want to solve for either the voltage, current, or power already knowing the other two, similar for $P=I^2R$, when you want to solve for an unknown already having knowledge of the other two. The last equation you get by noting that,

$P=IV=I^2R$, hence

$V=IR$ or $I=\frac{V}{R}$

plugging this into, the first equation you get
$P=\frac{V^2}{R}$